# Javascript Object Literal value as Array Presentation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
function __sort_number(list) {
  var anum = list.sort(function  __asort(a, b) {
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
 });

 anum.reverse();

 return anum;
}

// list = [1,5,3,6,2]

function evaluate_rank(list) {

 var sorted_list = __sort_number(list);

 // expected output : [6,5,3,2,1]

 var my_return = {
  'original' : list,
  'sorted' : sorted_list
 };

 // expected output : { original : [1,5,3,6,2], sorted : [6,5,3,2,1] }

 console.log(my_return);

 // when i view the object on the console dev tools
 // the arrays are sorted in ascending order
 // but when i tried using a for loop to check the values
 // being iterated is correct on sorted


 for (var i = 0; i < my_return.sorted.length; i++) {
   console.log(my_return.sorted[i]);
 }

 // expected output : 6 5 3 2 1
 // actual output : 6 5 3 2 1
}

evaluate_rank([1,5,3,6,2]);
```

is there any setting that should be done on creating the object
so that if i want to view the real value being saved on the object
is the same value that i am expecting so it would not create a **confusion**.

Answer (score 0):

Returning value after `sort` method is optional, `sort` method will sort the array on which it is called upon.

You can make a copy of the array before applying sort on it.

Make it

```
    var anum = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( list ) ).sort(function  __asort(a, b) {
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    });
```

or your usecase and better performance

```
    var anum = list.slice(0).sort(function  __asort(a, b) {
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    });
```